# how to set font size 100% of the browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to figure out how to set a the size of a font to be height/width = 100% of a browser window and make it responsive.

I understand it will be mangled - but I want the font to be 100% width and 100% height.

essentially

```
<div (set to responsive 100% of browser)>
  <p class="100by100">
    sample
  </p>
</div>
```

where "Sample" is always 100% of the bowser width and height.

thanks

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container

Comment: my question is a little different. I want to force the font size to be 100% of h and 100 of w. the view ports setting just scales the font up or down.

Comment: So you want to stretch the text to fill the viewport in _both_ dimensions? That is not possible using `font-size`. You might want to look into `transform:scale()` for that.

Comment: Font size change proportionally.  100% of h and w of the viewport would result in a distorted font which, AFAIK, is not possible...  Maybe you can use an image instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work, but I had to use javascript to set the `transform` on the inner element. https://jsfiddle.net/ynheeut3/

html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="fill">sample</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#fill {
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

javascript:

```
function fillWithText () {
  var fill = document.getElementById('fill');
  var container = document.getElementById('container');

  var totalHeight = container.clientHeight;
  var totalWidth = container.clientWidth;

  var currentHeight = fill.clientHeight;
  var currentWidth = fill.clientWidth;

  var scaleX = totalWidth / currentWidth;
  var scaleY = totalHeight / currentHeight;

  fill.style.transform = 'scale(' + scaleX + ',' + scaleY + ')';
};
window.addEventListener('resize', fillWithText, false);
fillWithText();
```

Comment: awesome - this is exactly - what I needed - however when I put all the code in html - it only take the full screen if I resize the bowser. is there a onload required ?

Comment: Yeah. The code has to run after the DOM is initialized.

Comment: <body onload="fillWithText()">